# I want to generate a pdf which will be sent by e-mail to all the related contacts of an opportunity - Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I want to generate a pdf which will be sent by e-mail to all the related contacts of an opportunity showing the opportunity details when this opportunity will be closed.
For this, I used VisualForce Page & an appropriate controller and a trigger which will fire and send the pdf by email to the related contacts of an opportunity when the opportunity will be closed.

--The problem is that when I want to test it in a trial org: When I want to pass the stage of an opportunity with the appropriate related contact to stagename = closed won or even closed lost I cannot! I have always an error triggered in red showing me: Error! You cannot change the stage of this opportunity contact your administrator... I tried to opened the debug log in the developer console but I found nothing, Can someone help me please? Thankss

The controller:

```
public class OpportunityPDFController {

    public Opportunity opportunity { get; set; }
    public list<Contact> relatedContacts {get; set;}

    public OpportunityPDFController() {
        // Get the Id parameter from the Visualforce page URL
        String opportunityId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

        // Query the opportunity record
        opportunity = [SELECT Id, Name, CloseDate, StageName, Amount, Probability, Description FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opportunityId];
    }
}
```

The Trigger:

```
    trigger ClosedOpportunityEmail on Opportunity (after update) {
    // Check if the opportunity is closed
    List<Opportunity> closedOpportunities = new List<Opportunity>();
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        if (opp.StageName == 'Closed Won' || opp.StageName == 'Closed Lost') {
            closedOpportunities.add(opp);
        }
    }
    
    // Retrieve related contacts for closed opportunities
    List<Contact> relatedContacts = new List<Contact>();
    for (Opportunity opp : closedOpportunities) {
        List<OpportunityContactRole> oppRoles = [SELECT ContactId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId = :opp.Id];
        for (OpportunityContactRole role : oppRoles) {
            relatedContacts.add([SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE Id = :role.ContactId]);
        }
    }
    
    // Generate PDF and send email to related contacts
    if (!relatedContacts.isEmpty()) {
        for (Contact contact : relatedContacts) {
            // Generate PDF using Visualforce
            PageReference pdfPage = Page.OpportunityPDFPage;
            pdfPage.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(closedOpportunities[0].Id)); // pass the Id of the closed opportunity to the Visualforce page
            Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();
            
            // Create and send email using Messaging.SingleEmailMessage class
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            email.setToAddresses(new List<String>{contact.Email});
            email.setSubject('Opportunity Closed: ' + closedOpportunities[0].Name);
            email.setHtmlBody('Hello ' + contact.Name + ',<br/><br/>Please find attached a complete PDF with the details of the closed opportunity.<br/><br/>Best regards,');
            
            // Attach PDF to email
            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            attachment.setFileName(closedOpportunities[0].Name + '.pdf');
            attachment.setContentType('application/pdf');
            attachment.setBody(pdfBlob);
            email.setFileAttachments(new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>{attachment});
            
            // Send email
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] sendResults = Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{email});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says: "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem". Your current title does not do so , and in the question you are repeating yourself.

Comment: I did put the code between three backticks "`"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a validation rule or custom error thrown from Opportunity trigger using "addError" or exception. You probably won't have this problem if you rebuild in another clean org. Or have developer console /debugging on when trying to close the deal. You should be able to determine what throws the error, for example validation rule's name.

But... From what I remember "getcontentaspdf" counts as a callout so ideally it'd be called with some asynchronous code like @future